# Java appserver to be iniated in Java application

Tags: java, servlets, applet, appserver

I'm looking for an Java based Application server which should be controllable within an Java application. I want to be able to start/stop the server within the application.

So far most App servers I looked at Glassfish, JBoss, are all controlled from the OS instead of being able to integrate into an existing Java Application.

Comment: Do you actually need a full-fledged appliction server or will something like Jetty work for you?

Comment: Maybe even Netty? http://www.jboss.org/netty

Comment: FWIW, there's [embedded glassfish](http://embedded-glassfish.java.net/), which is kind of interesting.

Comment: There's also embedded Tomcat and JBoss. Basically, every 100% pure Java server is embeddable. For hints, just google "embedded tomcat", "embedded jboss", "embedded glassfish", etc. By the way, you'd really need to sign your applet, else it just won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a look at Winstone or Jetty, they are easy to embed in an application:

- http://winstone.sourceforge.net
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty

Comment: I second the Jetty suggestion. If you interested in starting a war file from the command line, look at [Jetty Runner](http://blogs.webtide.com/janb/entry/jetty_runner)